# Code running too slow on large text files

Tags: vb.net, performance, text

I have some very large files to reformat and it takes hours instead of a couple of minutes. I am trying to speed it up a lot.

Input files are hundreds of millions of lines, 7 - 9 GB

How might I speed this Up? Thanks

Example input file contents...

```
# FIELD_RECORD_NO                Col:     1 -    15 Decs:   3 Mult: 1.000000 MEAN
# SHOTLINE_NUMBER                Col:    16 -    30 Decs:   3 Mult: 1.000000 MEAN
# SHOT_POINT_NO                  Col:    31 -    45 Decs:   3 Mult: 1.000000 MEAN
# RECEIVERLINE_NUMBER            Col:    46 -    60 Decs:   3 Mult: 1.000000 MEAN
# FIELD_STATION_NUMBER           Col:    61 -    75 Decs:   3 Mult: 1.000000 MEAN
# CHANNEL_NO                     Col:    76 -    90 Decs:   3 Mult: 1.000000 MEAN
      1.000       5177.000       2006.000       2001.000       5106.000          1.000                                                                                                                 
      1.000       5177.000       2006.000       2001.000       5107.000          2.000                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
      1.000       5177.000       2006.000       2001.000       5109.000          3.000                                                                                                                 
      1.000       5177.000       2006.000       2001.000       5110.000          4.000                                                                                                                 
      1.000       5177.000       2006.000       2001.000       5111.000          5.000                                                                                                                 
      1.000       5177.000       2006.000       2001.000       5112.000          6.000                                                                                                                 
      1.000       5177.000       2006.000       2001.000       5113.000          7.000                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
      1.000       5177.000       2006.000       2001.000       5115.000          8.000                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
      2.000       5177.000       2006.000       2001.000       5106.000          1.000                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
      2.000       5177.000       2006.000       2001.000       5108.000          2.000                                                                                                                 
      2.000       5177.000       2006.000       2001.000       5109.000          3.000                                                                                                                 
      2.000       5177.000       2006.000       2001.000       5110.000          4.000                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
      2.000       5177.000       2006.000       2001.000       5112.000          5.000                                                                                                                 
      2.000       5177.000       2006.000       2001.000       5113.000          6.000                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
      2.000       5177.000       2006.000       2001.000       5115.000          7.000
```

Example output file contents...

```
H00 SPS format version number   SPS 2.1;
X             11    5177.00   2006.001    1    21   2001.00   5106.00   5107.00-
X             11    5177.00   2006.001    3    71   2001.00   5109.00   5113.00-
X             11    5177.00   2006.001    8    81   2001.00   5115.00   5115.00-
X             21    5177.00   2006.001    1    11   2001.00   5106.00   5106.00-
X             21    5177.00   2006.001    2    41   2001.00   5108.00   5110.00-
X             21    5177.00   2006.001    5    61   2001.00   5112.00   5113.00-
X             21    5177.00   2006.001    7    71   2001.00   5115.00   5115.00-
```

Code...

```
       Option Strict On
    Public Class Main

  Public Sub ImportVistaHeaderFile()
        'On Error Resume Next
        Dim stime As DateTime, etime As DateTime
        Dim Readcnt As Integer
        Readcnt = 0

        stime = DateTime.Now
        Dim strm As System.IO.Stream

        Dim FFID As String = CStr(0)
        Dim SL As String = CStr(0)
        Dim SP As String = CStr(0)
        Dim RL As String = CStr(0)
        Dim RP As String = CStr(0)

        Dim OldFFID As String = CStr(0)
        Dim OldSL As String = CStr(0)
        Dim OldSP As String = CStr(0)
        Dim OldRL As String = CStr(0)
        Dim OldRP As String = CStr(0)
        Dim OldCH As String = CStr(0)

        Dim FRP As String = CStr(0)

        Dim FCH As String = CStr(0)
        Dim LCH As String = CStr(0)

        Dim ChCnt As Integer = 0

        Dim XPSFile As String
        Dim outfile As System.IO.StreamWriter

        Main.OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "Text Files (*.acs)|*.asc"
        Main.OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()

        strm = Main.OpenFileDialog1.OpenFile()

        Main.ToolStripStatusLabel1.Text = Main.OpenFileDialog1.FileName.ToString()

        XPSFile = Main.OpenFileDialog1.FileName.ToString() & ".xps"

        outfile = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter(XPSFile, False)
        outfile.WriteLine("H00 SPS format version number   SPS 2.1;")
        outfile.Close()

        Main.ToolStripStatusLabel3.Text = XPSFile
        Main.Refresh()

        If Not (strm Is Nothing) Then
            Dim fileReader As System.IO.StreamReader
            fileReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileReader(Main.ToolStripStatusLabel1.Text)

            Dim stringReader As String
            While (fileReader.Peek() >= 0)
                Readcnt = Readcnt + 1
                'read line from file
                stringReader = fileReader.ReadLine()
                'filter headers
                If Not stringReader.Contains("#") Then
                    'reformat data
                    Dim vals() As String = stringReader.Split(CChar(" "))
                    stringReader = String.Join("", vals)
                    vals = stringReader.Split(CChar("."))

                    ChCnt = ChCnt + 1

                    FFID = vals(0)
                    SL = vals(1).TrimStart("0"c)
                    SP = vals(2).TrimStart("0"c)
                    RL = vals(3).TrimStart("0"c)
                    RP = vals(4).TrimStart("0"c)

                    If CDbl(OldFFID) = 0 Then
                        'new file
                        OldFFID = FFID
                        OldSL = SL
                        OldSP = SP
                        OldRL = RL
                        OldRP = RP

                    End If

                    If FFID = OldFFID Then
                        'same ffid
                        If SL = OldSL Then
                            'same SL
                            If SP = OldSP Then
                                'same SP
                                If RL = OldRL Then
                                    'same RL
                                    If CDbl(RP) = CDbl(OldRP) + 1 Then
                                        'consecutive RP
                                        If CDbl(FRP) = 0 Then
                                            FRP = CStr(CDbl(RP) - 1)
                                        End If
                                        'consecutive RPs

                                        OldFFID = FFID
                                        OldSL = SL
                                        OldSP = SP
                                        OldRL = RL
                                        OldRP = RP

                                    Else
                                        If Not RP = OldRP Then
                                            'RP Gap
                                            'MsgBox("Receiver gap")
                                            If CDbl(FRP) = 0 Then
                                                FRP = OldRP
                                                If CDbl(FRP) = 0 Then
                                                    MsgBox("FRP = 0")
                                                End If
                                            End If

                                            LCH = CStr(ChCnt - 1)
                                            FCH = CStr(CDbl(LCH) - (CDbl(OldRP) - CDbl(FRP)))

                                            'write data to file
                                            WriteXPS(OldFFID, OldSL, OldSP, FCH, LCH, OldRL, FRP, OldRP, "Gap", XPSFile)

                                            OldRP = RP

                                            FRP = CStr(0)

                                        End If
                                    End If
                                Else
                                    'New RL 
                                    'write data to file
                                    If CDbl(FRP) = 0 Then
                                        FRP = OldRP
                                        If CDbl(FRP) = 0 Then
                                            MsgBox("FRP = 0")
                                        End If
                                    End If

                                    LCH = CStr(ChCnt - 1)
                                    FCH = CStr(CDbl(LCH) - (CDbl(OldRP) - CDbl(FRP)))

                                    WriteXPS(OldFFID, OldSL, OldSP, FCH, LCH, OldRL, FRP, OldRP, "RL", XPSFile)

                                    OldRL = RL
                                    OldRP = RP

                                    FRP = CStr(0)

                                End If
                            Else
                                'New SP
                                MsgBox("Duplicate FFID is not supported by SEG XPS files. FFID " & OldFFID & " SP " & OldSL & OldSP & " SP " & SL & SP)

                                OldFFID = FFID
                                OldSL = SL
                                OldSP = SP
                                OldRL = RL
                                OldRP = RP

                                FRP = CStr(0)
                            End If
                        Else
                            'New SL
                            MsgBox("Duplicate FFID is not supported by SEG XPS files. FFID " & OldFFID & " SP " & OldSL & OldSP & " SP " & SL & SP)

                            OldFFID = FFID
                            OldSL = SL
                            OldSP = SP
                            OldRL = RL
                            OldRP = RP

                            FRP = CStr(0)
                        End If
                    Else
                        'New FFID
                        'MsgBox("New FFID")

                        'write data to file
                        If CDbl(FRP) = 0 Then
                            FRP = OldRP
                            If CDbl(FRP) = 0 Then
                                MsgBox("FRP = 0")
                            End If

                        End If

                        LCH = CStr(ChCnt - 1)
                        FCH = CStr(CDbl(LCH) - (CDbl(OldRP) - CDbl(FRP)))
                        WriteXPS(OldFFID, OldSL, OldSP, FCH, LCH, OldRL, FRP, OldRP, "FFID", XPSFile)

                        OldFFID = FFID
                        OldSL = SL
                        OldSP = SP
                        OldRL = RL
                        OldRP = RP

                        ChCnt = 1

                        FRP = CStr(0)
                    End If
                End If
            End While
            strm.Close()
            Main.ToolStripStatusLabel1.Text = ""
            Main.ToolStripStatusLabel2.Text = ""
            Main.ToolStripStatusLabel3.Text = ""
            'MessageBox.Show("File creation complete")

            etime = DateTime.Now
            MsgBox(DateDiff(DateInterval.Second, stime, etime) & " " & Readcnt)
        End If
    End Sub
```

code..

```
 Private Sub WriteXPS(FFID As String, SL As String, SP As String, FCH As String, LCH As String, RL As String, FRP As String, LRP As String, XPSFile As String)
        Dim outfile As System.IO.StreamWriter = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter(XPSFile, True)
        If FFID Mod 10 = 0 Then
             Me.ToolStripStatusLabel2.Text = "Processing Files: " & FFID + 1 & "-" & FFID + 10
            Me.Refresh()
        End If


        FFID = FFID.PadLeft(14)
        SL = SL.PadLeft(8)
        SP = SP.PadLeft(7)
        FCH = FCH.PadLeft(5)
        LCH = LCH.PadLeft(5)
        RL = RL.PadLeft(7)
        FRP = FRP.PadLeft(7)
        LRP = LRP.PadLeft(7)
        outfile = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter(XPSFile, True)
        outfile.WriteLine("X," & FFID & "1," & SL & ".00," & SP & ".001," & FCH & LCH & "1," & RL & ".00," & FRP & ".00," & LRP & ".00-")
        outfile.Close()
    End Sub
```

Comment: If it's an O(n) problem, where n = # of lines, then there's nothing you can do about it except chunk it and process in separate threads.

Comment: Would it be because of the file opening and closing? Should I just leave it open?

Comment: Not sure to follow your code correctly, but are you opening and closing the output file for every single line reformatted?

Comment: I would leave the input file open for reading and the output file open for writing the whole time.

Comment: I would use the format capabilities of StreamWriter and get rid of the PadLeft and string concat things - all of WriteXPS could be one line of code

Comment: @Plutonix just testing it, and it gains a 30% on 100000 loop.

Comment: @Steve I'd say that is a nice start (assuming "gain" == performance gain, not time elapsed gain).  Next: Turn on OPTION STRICT: `Dim SL As String = 0`

Comment: Also, I suggest not writing to the ToolStripStatusLabel2.Text for every output line.

Comment: Run profiler, see which line it points on.

Comment: Was this one purpose? "Text Files (*.acs)|*.asc"

Comment: yes, the input file is of a consistent format.

Comment: You could use the [File.AppendAllText Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143356%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of the StreamWriter and OpenTextFileWriter. Using [String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to compose the output line will make it faster. If you use Plutonix's other recommendation of [Option Strict On](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) and make all the corrections it suggests, you might gain a lot of speed as the corrections will give it a lot less work to do.

Comment: I am going to try Option Strict On again.. When I tried it I started getting file access errors.

Comment: Updated the code with Option Strict On.. It seems to be working. I believe it is slow partly due to the input formatting. When I removed the output formatting it was a lot faster.

Comment: I am trying to figure out how to leave the output file open. Not sure how much time that is costing but it must be a lot.

Comment: I updated the code. Removed the CH field from import and used the line cnt instead. Seems a bit faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend starting by profiling your application, and would recommend either:

- [YourKit](http://www.yourkit.com/)
- [RedGate's Ants Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/)

This should tell you where your performance issues lie.

Note: both vendors provide trial versions.

I'd also recommend finding the elapsed time required for reading and writing the files without any computation (i.e. splitting the line and converting the fields to decimals). If this is close to your current elapsed time with computation then it is unlikely that you can make it run much faster.

Comment: YourKit results - WriteXPS = 66% - String.Split = 16% - String.Join = 9% ... If I am reading this correctly I could speed it up by doing some faster formatting on the input and a lot on the output. Still have not accomplished leaving the output file open so I think that is included in the time delay represented.

Comment: Yes, looks like there's potential for optimization there, the String.Split, String.Join look like a good start point

Comment: Strange that it is so slow. I have a program that writes these files but it does not write them correctly. A 40,000,000 line input writes the output file of 400,000 lines in 15 secs. It's taking me 9 hrs.

Comment: 9 hours seems a little too long, try timing how long it takes to do 'While (fileReader.Peek() >= 0) fileReader.ReadLine() End While`. That should give some indication of how fast it could go. Also consider using `fileReader.EndOfStream` instead of `fileReader.Peek()`

Comment: 'While (fileReader.Peek() >= 0) fileReader.ReadLine() End While` 12837765 lines 26 seconds. Same result with EndOfStream.

Comment: That seems a long way from 9 hours, so the next thing to do would be to add in the writes but just write empty data, i.e. don't do the computation, for example write a line with fixed data say every 100th read line

Comment: Update: I think the problem is in the write, you are recreating the writer for each write in `WriteXPS`, i.e. `OpenTextFileWriter(XPSFile, True)`, and I believe this may be an expensive operation. Instead you could hold a Dictionary of open file handles (one for each unique file name) and reuse them, then at the end close them all.

Comment: Okay I'll try that..  I ran this and got 26 seconds for 1000000 lines....    'stime = DateTime.Now ChCnt = 1 While Not (fileReader.EndOfStream) stringReader = (fileReader.ReadLine()) Do Until ChCnt = 1000000  ChCnt = ChCnt + 1 If Not stringReader.Contains("#") Then Dim vals() As String = stringReader.Split(CChar(" "))
                        stringReader = String.Join("", vals)
                        vals = stringReader.Split(CChar("."))

                    End If
                Loop
            End While
            etime = DateTime.Now '

Comment: Added this to the code above and not time was added... 'FFID = vals(0)
                        SL = vals(1).TrimStart("0"c)
                        SP = vals(2).TrimStart("0"c)
                        RL = vals(3).TrimStart("0"c)
                        RP = vals(4).TrimStart("0"c)'

Comment: Yep, looks like the writing is taking an enormous amount of time.

Comment: I run the full code above with writeline off and it runs 75,000 lines in 6 seconds. So I am going to be looking at another write option.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the main problem by leaving the file open.

This version of the code reads 37,120,000 + lines and outputs 440,000 + lines in 1004 seconds.

Thanks to everyone for all of the help.

Best Regards

```
Option Strict On
Module MainModule

    Public Sub ImportVistaHeaderFile()
        'On Error Resume Next

        Dim stime As DateTime
        Dim etime As DateTime
        Dim Readcnt As Long = 0
        Dim Writecnt As Long = 0
        Dim TRcnt As Long = 0
        Dim ChCnt As Long = 0
        Dim Duplicates As Long = 0

        stime = DateTime.Now
        etime = DateTime.Now

        Dim strm As System.IO.Stream
        Dim outfile As System.IO.StreamWriter
        Dim WrtLogfile As System.IO.StreamWriter

        Dim XPSFile As String = CStr(0)
        Dim Logfile As String = CStr(0)

        Dim FFID As String = CStr(0)
        Dim SL As String = CStr(0)
        Dim SP As String = CStr(0)
        Dim RL As String = CStr(0)
        Dim RP As String = CStr(0)

        Dim FRP As String = CStr(0)
        Dim FCH As String = CStr(0)
        Dim LCH As String = CStr(0)

        Dim OldFFID As String = CStr(0)
        Dim OldSL As String = CStr(0)
        Dim OldSP As String = CStr(0)
        Dim OldRL As String = CStr(0)
        Dim OldRP As String = CStr(0)
        Dim OldCH As String = CStr(0)

        Dim wFFID As String = CStr(0)
        Dim wSL As String = CStr(0)
        Dim wSP As String = CStr(0)
        Dim wFCH As String = CStr(0)
        Dim wLCH As String = CStr(0)
        Dim wRL As String = CStr(0)
        Dim wFRP As String = CStr(0)
        Dim wRP As String = CStr(0)

        Main.OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "Text Files (*.acs)|*.asc"
        Main.OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()

        strm = Main.OpenFileDialog1.OpenFile()

        'update form with input file
        Main.ToolStripStatusLabel1.Text = Main.OpenFileDialog1.FileName.ToString()
        Main.Refresh()

        XPSFile = Main.OpenFileDialog1.FileName.ToString() & ".xps"
        Logfile = FileIO.FileSystem.GetName(XPSFile) & ".log"

        'open log file and write header
        WrtLogfile = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter(Logfile, False)
        WrtLogfile.WriteLine("# Import file " & Main.OpenFileDialog1.FileName.ToString & " at " & stime)
        WrtLogfile.WriteLine()
        WrtLogfile.Close()

        'open logfile for loging
        WrtLogfile = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter(Logfile, True)

        'open output file and write header
        outfile = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter(XPSFile, False)
        outfile.WriteLine("H00 SPS format version number   SPS 2.1;")
        outfile.Close()

        'open file for data
        outfile = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter(XPSFile, True)

        Main.ToolStripStatusLabel3.Text = XPSFile
        Main.Refresh()

        If Not (strm Is Nothing) Then
            Dim fileReader As System.IO.StreamReader
            fileReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileReader(Main.ToolStripStatusLabel1.Text)

            Dim stringReader As String
            While (fileReader.Peek() >= 0)

                'read line from file
                stringReader = fileReader.ReadLine()
                'filter headers
                If Not stringReader.Contains("#") Then
                    'reformat data
                    Readcnt = Readcnt + 1
                    Dim vals() As String = stringReader.Split(CChar(" "))
                    stringReader = String.Join("", vals)
                    vals = stringReader.Split(CChar("."))

                    ChCnt = ChCnt + 1

                    FFID = vals(0)
                    SL = vals(1).TrimStart("0"c)
                    SP = vals(2).TrimStart("0"c)
                    RL = vals(3).TrimStart("0"c)
                    RP = vals(4).TrimStart("0"c)

                    If CDbl(OldFFID) = 0 Then
                        'new file
                        OldFFID = FFID
                        OldSL = SL
                        OldSP = SP
                        OldRL = RL
                        OldRP = RP

                    End If

                    If FFID = OldFFID Then
                        'same ffid
                        If SL = OldSL Then
                            'same SL
                            If SP = OldSP Then
                                'same SP
                                If RL = OldRL Then
                                    'same RL
                                    If CDbl(RP) = CDbl(OldRP) + 1 Then

                                        If CDbl(FRP) = 0 Then
                                            FRP = CStr(CDbl(RP) - 1)
                                        End If
                                        'consecutive RP
                                        OldFFID = FFID
                                        OldSL = SL
                                        OldSP = SP
                                        OldRL = RL
                                        OldRP = RP

                                    Else
                                        If Not RP = OldRP Then
                                            'RP Gap
                                            If CDbl(FRP) = 0 Then
                                                FRP = OldRP
                                                If CDbl(FRP) = 0 Then
                                                    MsgBox("FRP = 0")
                                                End If
                                            End If

                                            LCH = CStr(ChCnt - 1)
                                            FCH = CStr(CDbl(LCH) - (CDbl(OldRP) - CDbl(FRP)))

                                            If CDbl(FFID) Mod 10 = 0 Then
                                                Main.ToolStripStatusLabel2.Text = "Processing FFID: " & CDbl(FFID) - 9 & "-" & FFID
                                                Main.Refresh()
                                            End If

                                            wFFID = OldFFID.PadLeft(14)
                                            wSL = OldSL.PadLeft(8)
                                            wSP = OldSP.PadLeft(7)
                                            wFCH = FCH.PadLeft(5)
                                            wLCH = LCH.PadLeft(5)
                                            wRL = OldRL.PadLeft(7)
                                            wFRP = FRP.PadLeft(7)
                                            wRP = OldRP.PadLeft(7)

                                            'write data to file

                                            outfile.Write("X")
                                            outfile.Write(wFFID)
                                            outfile.Write("1")
                                            outfile.Write(wSL)
                                            outfile.Write(".00")
                                            outfile.Write(wSP)
                                            outfile.Write(".001")
                                            outfile.Write(wFCH)
                                            outfile.Write(wLCH)
                                            outfile.Write("1")
                                            outfile.Write(wRL)
                                            outfile.Write(".00")
                                            outfile.Write(wFRP)
                                            outfile.Write(".00")
                                            outfile.Write(wRP)
                                            outfile.WriteLine(".00-")

                                            TRcnt = CLng(TRcnt + (CDbl(LCH) - CDbl(FCH) + 1))
                                            Writecnt = Writecnt + 1

                                            OldRP = RP

                                            FRP = CStr(0)
                                        Else
                                            If Not Readcnt = 1 Then

                                                If CDbl(FRP) = 0 Then
                                                    FRP = OldRP
                                                    If CDbl(FRP) = 0 Then
                                                        MsgBox("FRP = 0")
                                                    End If

                                                End If
                                                LCH = CStr(ChCnt - 1)
                                                FCH = CStr(CDbl(LCH) - (CDbl(OldRP) - CDbl(FRP)))

                                                If CDbl(FFID) Mod 10 = 0 Then
                                                    Main.ToolStripStatusLabel2.Text = "Processing FFID: " & CDbl(FFID) - 9 & "-" & FFID
                                                    Main.Refresh()
                                                End If

                                                wFFID = OldFFID.PadLeft(14)
                                                wSL = OldSL.PadLeft(8)
                                                wSP = OldSP.PadLeft(7)
                                                wFCH = FCH.PadLeft(5)
                                                wLCH = LCH.PadLeft(5)
                                                wRL = OldRL.PadLeft(7)
                                                wFRP = FRP.PadLeft(7)
                                                wRP = OldRP.PadLeft(7)

                                                'write data to file

                                                outfile.Write("X")
                                                outfile.Write(wFFID)
                                                outfile.Write("1")
                                                outfile.Write(wSL)
                                                outfile.Write(".00")
                                                outfile.Write(wSP)
                                                outfile.Write(".001")
                                                outfile.Write(wFCH)
                                                outfile.Write(wLCH)
                                                outfile.Write("1")
                                                outfile.Write(wRL)
                                                outfile.Write(".00")
                                                outfile.Write(wFRP)
                                                outfile.Write(".00")
                                                outfile.Write(wRP)
                                                outfile.WriteLine(".00-")

                                                TRcnt = CLng(TRcnt + (CDbl(LCH) - CDbl(FCH) + 1))
                                                Writecnt = Writecnt + 1

                                                OldRP = RP

                                                FRP = CStr(0)

                                                WrtLogfile.WriteLine("Duplicate RP - FFID: " & FFID & "    SL: " & SL & "    SP" & SP & "    RL: " & RL & "    RP " & RP & "    CH: " & CDbl(LCH) + 1)

                                                Duplicates = Duplicates + 1

                                            End If
                                            End If
                                    End If
                                Else
                                    'New RL 

                                    If CDbl(FRP) = 0 Then
                                        FRP = OldRP
                                        If CDbl(FRP) = 0 Then
                                            MsgBox("FRP = 0")
                                        End If
                                    End If

                                    LCH = CStr(ChCnt - 1)
                                    FCH = CStr(CDbl(LCH) - (CDbl(OldRP) - CDbl(FRP)))

                                    If CDbl(FFID) Mod 10 = 0 Then
                                        Main.ToolStripStatusLabel2.Text = "Processing FFID: " & CDbl(FFID) - 9 & "-" & FFID
                                        Main.Refresh()
                                    End If

                                    wFFID = OldFFID.PadLeft(14)
                                    wSL = OldSL.PadLeft(8)
                                    wSP = OldSP.PadLeft(7)
                                    wFCH = FCH.PadLeft(5)
                                    wLCH = LCH.PadLeft(5)
                                    wRL = OldRL.PadLeft(7)
                                    wFRP = FRP.PadLeft(7)
                                    wRP = OldRP.PadLeft(7)

                                    'write data to file

                                    outfile.Write("X")
                                    outfile.Write(wFFID)
                                    outfile.Write("1")
                                    outfile.Write(wSL)
                                    outfile.Write(".00")
                                    outfile.Write(wSP)
                                    outfile.Write(".001")
                                    outfile.Write(wFCH)
                                    outfile.Write(wLCH)
                                    outfile.Write("1")
                                    outfile.Write(wRL)
                                    outfile.Write(".00")
                                    outfile.Write(wFRP)
                                    outfile.Write(".00")
                                    outfile.Write(wRP)
                                    outfile.WriteLine(".00-")

                                    TRcnt = CLng(TRcnt + (CDbl(LCH) - CDbl(FCH) + 1))
                                    Writecnt = Writecnt + 1

                                    OldRL = RL
                                    OldRP = RP

                                    FRP = CStr(0)
                                End If
                            Else
                                'New SP
                                MsgBox("Duplicate FFID is not supported by SEG XPS files. FFID " & OldFFID & " SP " & OldSL & OldSP & " SP " & SL & SP)

                                OldFFID = FFID
                                OldSL = SL
                                OldSP = SP
                                OldRL = RL
                                OldRP = RP

                                FRP = CStr(0)
                            End If
                        Else
                            'New SL
                            MsgBox("Duplicate FFID is not supported by SEG XPS files. FFID " & OldFFID & " SP " & OldSL & OldSP & " SP " & SL & SP)

                            OldFFID = FFID
                            OldSL = SL
                            OldSP = SP
                            OldRL = RL
                            OldRP = RP

                            FRP = CStr(0)
                        End If
                    Else
                        'New FFID

                        If CDbl(FRP) = 0 Then
                            FRP = OldRP
                            If CDbl(FRP) = 0 Then
                                MsgBox("FRP = 0")
                            End If

                        End If

                        LCH = CStr(ChCnt - 1)
                        FCH = CStr(CDbl(LCH) - (CDbl(OldRP) - CDbl(FRP)))

                        If CDbl(FFID) Mod 10 = 0 Then
                            Main.ToolStripStatusLabel2.Text = "Processing FFID: " & CDbl(FFID) - 9 & "-" & FFID
                            Main.Refresh()
                        End If

                        wFFID = OldFFID.PadLeft(14)
                        wSL = OldSL.PadLeft(8)
                        wSP = OldSP.PadLeft(7)
                        wFCH = FCH.PadLeft(5)
                        wLCH = LCH.PadLeft(5)
                        wRL = OldRL.PadLeft(7)
                        wFRP = FRP.PadLeft(7)
                        wRP = OldRP.PadLeft(7)

                        'write data to file

                        outfile.Write("X")
                        outfile.Write(wFFID)
                        outfile.Write("1")
                        outfile.Write(wSL)
                        outfile.Write(".00")
                        outfile.Write(wSP)
                        outfile.Write(".001")
                        outfile.Write(wFCH)
                        outfile.Write(wLCH)
                        outfile.Write("1")
                        outfile.Write(wRL)
                        outfile.Write(".00")
                        outfile.Write(wFRP)
                        outfile.Write(".00")
                        outfile.Write(wRP)
                        outfile.WriteLine(".00-")

                        TRcnt = CLng(TRcnt + (CDbl(LCH) - CDbl(FCH) + 1))
                        Writecnt = Writecnt + 1

                        OldFFID = FFID
                        OldSL = SL
                        OldSP = SP
                        OldRL = RL
                        OldRP = RP

                        ChCnt = 1

                        FRP = CStr(0)
                    End If
                End If
            End While

            'close input file
            strm.Close()

            'write buffer
            If CDbl(FRP) = 0 Then
                FRP = OldRP
                If CDbl(FRP) = 0 Then
                    MsgBox("FRP = 0")
                End If

            End If
            LCH = CStr(ChCnt)
            FCH = CStr(CDbl(LCH) - (CDbl(OldRP) - CDbl(FRP)))

            If CDbl(FFID) Mod 10 = 0 Then
                Main.ToolStripStatusLabel2.Text = "Processing FFID: " & CDbl(FFID) - 9 & "-" & FFID
                Main.Refresh()
            End If

            wFFID = OldFFID.PadLeft(14)
            wSL = OldSL.PadLeft(8)
            wSP = OldSP.PadLeft(7)
            wFCH = FCH.PadLeft(5)
            wLCH = LCH.PadLeft(5)
            wRL = OldRL.PadLeft(7)
            wFRP = FRP.PadLeft(7)
            wRP = OldRP.PadLeft(7)

            'write data to file

            outfile.Write("X")
            outfile.Write(wFFID)
            outfile.Write("1")
            outfile.Write(wSL)
            outfile.Write(".00")
            outfile.Write(wSP)
            outfile.Write(".001")
            outfile.Write(wFCH)
            outfile.Write(wLCH)
            outfile.Write("1")
            outfile.Write(wRL)
            outfile.Write(".00")
            outfile.Write(wFRP)
            outfile.Write(".00")
            outfile.Write(wRP)
            outfile.WriteLine(".00-")

            TRcnt = CLng(TRcnt + (CDbl(LCH) - CDbl(FCH) + 1))
            Writecnt = Writecnt + 1

            OldRL = RL
            OldRP = RP

            FRP = CStr(0)

            'close output file
            outfile.Close()

            etime = DateTime.Now
            Main.ToolStripStatusLabel1.Text = XPSFile
            Main.ToolStripStatusLabel2.Text = "Traces " & TRcnt
            Main.ToolStripStatusLabel3.Text = Logfile

            'write status to logfile
            WrtLogfile.WriteLine()
            WrtLogfile.WriteLine()
            WrtLogfile.WriteLine("Total traces in " & Readcnt)
            WrtLogfile.WriteLine("Total traces out " & TRcnt)
            WrtLogfile.WriteLine("Duplicates traces found: " & Duplicates)
            WrtLogfile.WriteLine()
            WrtLogfile.WriteLine("# Export file " & Main.OpenFileDialog1.FileName.ToString & ".asc at " & etime)
            WrtLogfile.WriteLine()
            WrtLogfile.WriteLine("Total elapsed time " & DateDiff(DateInterval.Second, stime, etime) & " seconds")

            'close logfile
            WrtLogfile.Close()

        End If
    End Sub
End Module
```